# Java JNI Application Crash due to Stack Overflow

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I've written a Java application that uses JNI to call a custom native library. The library works fine we I pass in for small data arrays. However, larger data arrays cause a fatal error (EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW). The application's core dump shows the offending function _chkstk. Apparently, _chkstk is called by the compiler when you have more than one page of local variables in your function.

```
    ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

    Current thread (0x3590b800):  JavaThread "pool-2-thread-8" [_thread_in_native, id=11228, stack(0x0f7d0000,0x0f9d0000)]

    siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc00000fd, ExceptionInformation=0x00000000 0x0f7d0000 
...


    Stack: [0x0f7d0000,0x0f9d0000],  sp=0x0f9b7118,  free space=1948k
    Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
    C  [b.dll+0xbfc7]  _chkstk+0x27
    C  [b.dll+0xbf00]  more_calcs+0x60
    C  [b.dll+0xbe1c]  b+0x3c
    C  [a.dll+0x14b0]  more_calcs+0xc0
    C  [a.dll+0x109c]  calcs+0x3c
    C  [x.dll+0x1b75]  Java_com_...s+0x8f5
    j  com.s...(Ljava/lang/String;IIIII[D[D[D[[[I[[[[D[[[[[[D)[[[[D+0
```

A quick search lead me to Oracle's website which describes in detail what's happening [4.1.3 Crash due to Stack Overflow](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/crashes-137240.html) and suggests ways to correct the issue 1) increase the value of StackShadowPages (verifies a minimum amount of space remains on the stack) 2) increase the default thread stack size using the -Xssparameter.

What's not clear is by how much these values should be increased. Rather that a shotgun approach I would like to determine this mathematically. Can this be determined from the stack pointers in the dump?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot determine from the way it crashed how long the program might have run or how deep it might have gone if you let it.

It doesn't appear very deep so it would appear you are trying to allocate a large array on the stack instead of using the heap.  As the stack size is limited, I would use the native heap for such large allocations.

Of course this is more of a C programming question than a Java programming one.

Comment: agreed. it's a bit more complicated that I described however, the large multidimensional arrays are allocated in C (as contiguous memory and passed to FORTRAN). Perhaps the way I'm declaring the parameter in FORTRAN  real(C_DOUBLE), intent(in), dimension(0:7*3*2*99) :: bigarray is causing the allocation on the stack. New to FORTRAN. Need to investigate.

Comment: @javacavaj In the meantime you may have to use `-Xss` to increase the stack maximum.  Note: this affects all threads. :P

Answer (score 0):

**IBM specific**
Note that you can view the existing stack sizes with

```
java -verbose:sizes
```

When running a Java application, you can change the initial stack size for operating system threads with

```
java -Xmso512k <...other args to run your app..>
```

See [IBM Java -Xmso doc](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.aix.70.doc/diag/appendixes/cmdline/Xmso.html)